# How to configure AuthenticationSuccessHandler etc. only for /api/**

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

We are developing a standard Spring Boot web application with Thymeleaf templating, but have an API at `/api/**` which is called through AJAX.

We're using Spring Security's standard cookie based form authentication both for the application and the API. Whereas for the application we want Spring Security to behave in the default way, for the API, we want to provide custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` etc. for returning `200 OK` etc., instead of redirecting to *success* or *failure* urls.

I am unable to figure out how to configure this, using Java configuration. In the `configure` method, I tried to configure `http` two times, as below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
// For the API
http.antMatcher("/api/**")

    .formLogin()
        .successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
    .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint())

    .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .key(properties.getRememberMeKey())
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new LemonCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login/impersonate*").hasRole(GOOD_ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/logout/impersonate*").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

// For the application pages
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login/impersonate*").hasRole(GOOD_ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/logout/impersonate*").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
        .logout().permitAll()
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .key(properties.getRememberMeKey())
            .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
    .and()
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new LemonCsrfFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(switchUserFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
```

Comment: what do you mean by ** doesn't seem to work**, not returning 200 OK,but redirecting to success or failure urls for the /api/** calls?

Comment: I get a strange error saying CSRF token not being present.

Comment: you enabled `.csrf()` for your API requests too, have you bring that csrf header when you make you API call?

Comment: Yes, CSRF works well if there's just one `http` call. I guess calling `http` two times as above may be switching off Spring security or something. Is calling `http` multiple times, as I have done above, look ok?